# Erro ao dividir imagem ao meio usando Python

Tags: python, matemática, tipagem, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Estou tentando dividir uma imagem ao meio usando o código abaixo, mas estou tendo um erro de retorno.

Código:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread("IMD015.png")
width = img.shape

# Cut the image in half
width_cutoff = width / 2
s1 = img[:, width_cutoff]
s2 = img[:, width_cutoff:]

# Save each half
cv2.imsave("face1.png", s1)
cv2.imsave("face2.png", s2)

i1 = cv2.imread("face1.png")
i2 = cv2.imread("face2.png")
assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
assert i1.size == i2.size, "Different sizes."

pairs = zip(i1.getdata(), i2.getdata())
if len(i1.getbands()) == 1:
    # for gray-scale jpegs
    dif = sum(abs(p1-p2) for p1,p2 in pairs)
else:
    dif = sum(abs(c1-c2) for p1,p2 in pairs for c1,c2 in zip(p1,p2))

ncomponents = i1.size[0] * i1.size[1] * 3
print ("Difference (percentage):"+ str((dif / 255.0 * 100) / ncomponents))
```

Erro:

> ```
> line 10, in <module>
>     width_cutoff = width / 2
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
> ```

Sei que o erro está na divisão, mas como faço para corrigir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro é bem descritivo, você está pegando uma tupla e tentando dividir por 2. Você só pode dividir um número, não um conjunto de dados.

A documentação é bem falha, mas no fim consegui achar que a variável `img.shape` está recebendo mesmo uma tupla com alguns dados da imagem. Você não pode pegar essa tupla, mas pode desconstruí-la em variáveis e aí pegar uma dessas variáveis e fazer a divisão se algum dos elementos for um número, e de fato eu consegui inferir que é. Então para pegar a largura deveria ter feito isto:

```
_, width, _ = img.shape
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/MultiAssign.py).

Mesmo que não precise dos outros elementos preciso pegá-los, no caso eu usei `_` para descartá-los e não criar uma variável à toa.

Comment: deu certo, era isto mesmo. Muito obgdo

Comment: agora estou passando por este erro: line 19, in <module>
    assert i1.mode == i2.mode, "Different kinds of images."
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mode'

Comment: Este é outro erro e precisa ser em outra pergunta. De qualquer forma acho que está precisando de treinamento em programação. Parece que está tentando fazer códigos complexos sem sequer saber o básico, isto não costuma dar certo.

Comment: deu certo, so que percebi que essa divisao ao meio ele se da na imagem toda, e eu quero dividir no meio de acordo com minha regiao de interesse, que no meu caso é uma mancha de pele. Nessa pergunta que fiz, explica melhor o que estou querendo desenvolver, se puder me ajudar nessa, agradeço mt.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301086/how-to-identify-if-the-shapes-of-an-image-are-symmetric-or-asymmetric-using-open?noredirect=1#comment93492798_53301086

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343682/75104), outras formas de obter a largura.

#### .shape do OpenCV

Com um `print()` em `img.shape`, é possível verificar que uma tupla é retornada da seguinte maneira: `(altura, largura, número_de_canais)`

Ex.: `(600, 800, 3)`

Então cada valor pode ser obtido com: `height, width, channels = img.shape`

Acessar o elemento da tupla que corresponde à largura:

- `w = img.shape[1]`
- `w = img.shape[-2]`

Ou  o *slicing* do Python pode ser usado para obter somente a altura e largura:

- `h, w = img.shape[:2]`
- `h, w = img.shape[:-1]`

#### Numpy

A largura pode ser obtida com `w = np.size(img, 1)`

E a altura com `h = np.size(img, 0)`

E o canal com `c = np.size(img,2)`

#### PIL

Com a biblioteca PIL (*Python Imaging Library*)

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('3mNqf.png')
print(im.size)
width, height = im.size
w = im.size[0]
w = im.size[-2]
```